# "Unitary" extension of the normal field from the boundary of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, tangent-spaces

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $M$ be a $d$-dimensional properly embedded $C^2$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary and $\nu_{\partial M}$ denote the outward pointing unit normal field on $\partial M$.

Note that $\nu_{\partial M}$ is $C^1$-differentiable and hence, for any given open neighborhood $O$ of $\partial M$, there is a $\tilde\nu\in C^1(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)$ with $$\operatorname{supp}\tilde\nu\subseteq O\tag1$$ and $$\left.\tilde\nu\right|_{\partial M}=\nu_{\partial M}\tag2.$$

I've described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3812134/47771) how $\tilde\nu$ can be constructed.

> **Question**: Are we able to show that $O$ and $\tilde\nu$ can be chosen such that $$\left\|\tilde\nu(a)\right\|=1\tag3$$ for all $a\in U$ for some open $U\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ with $\partial M\subseteq U\subseteq O$?

Note that $(3)$ is clearly satisfied for all $a\in\partial M$, since $\tilde\nu(a)=\nu_{\partial M}(a)$.

Referring to the notation of [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3812134/47771) in my link, we may be able to chose $\rho_0$ appropriately.

Comment: If $\operatorname{supp}\bar{\nu}\subseteq O$, then $(3)$ cannot be satisfied unless $O=\mathbb{R}^n$. Do you mean to ask if you can find an open $U$ with $\partial M\subseteq U\subseteq O$ such that $\|\bar{\nu}|_{U}\|=1$?

Comment: @Kajelad Yes, sorry. That was confusing. I would like to show exactly what what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $\bar{\nu},O$ satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$and define an set
$$
U=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d:\|\bar{\nu}(x)\|>\frac{1}{2}\right\}
$$
Note that $\partial M\subset U\subseteq O$, and $U$ is open, since it is the preimage of an open set by a continuous function $\|\bar{\nu}\|$. Choose a smooth function function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ for $x\ge 1/4$.
Define a vector field $v$ by
$$
v(x)=f(\|\bar{\nu}(x)\|^2)\bar{\nu}
$$
Then $v$ is as smooth as $\bar{\nu}$ is, $\operatorname{supp}(v)\subseteq O$, $v|_{\partial M}=\nu$, and $\|v|_U\|=1$.

Comment: I've corrected the definition of $U$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the edit. Now it's clear. In arguments of the kind "choose a smooth function $f$ such that $f(x)=\ldots$ for $x\in\ldots$", which argument is needed to verify that such a function exists?

Comment: In this case, you can explicitly construct such a function $f$ using bump functions. There are various $C^k$ extension lemmas for more general cases, but they aren't needed here.

Comment: Sure. If I'm not missing something, the existence of your $f$ should follow in a black-box way from the theorem in [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3812134/47771) I've linked to in the question, since $[1/4,\infty)$ is closed, right?

Comment: Yes; that would suffice.

Comment: It might not be obvious (I intend to take $\theta=\nu_{\partial\Omega}$ later on), but I've got a follow-up question, which should be rather trivial, but I'm somehow unsure what I really can infer from the continuous embedding assumption. Maybe you can take a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3841261/47771.

Comment: Oh, and am I right that we can deduce that $0={\rm D}\left\|v\right\|(x)=\langle v(x),{\rm D}v(x)\rangle$ (or, equivalently, $\nabla\left\|v\right\|(x)={{\rm D}v(x)}^\ast v(x)=0$) for all $x\in U$? This should hold true, since $\left\|v\right\|=1$ on the open set $U$.