# Quotient space of $\{\theta\in\mathcal D(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d):\langle\theta(x),\nu_{∂Ω}(x)\rangle=0\text{ for all }x\in ∂Ω\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, smooth-manifolds, distribution-theory, quotient-spaces, manifolds-with-boundary

The following claim can be found in [Introduction to Shape Optimization](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642634710) (p. 58), but is missing rigor:

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $\Omega$ be a $d$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary, $\nu_{\partial\Omega}$ denote the outward-pointing unit normal field on $\partial\Omega$ and $$\mathcal V(\Omega):=\{\theta\in\mathcal D(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d):\langle\theta(x),\nu_{\partial\Omega}(x)\rangle=0\text{ for all }x\in\partial\Omega\}.$$

> The claim is that $$\mathcal D(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)/\mathcal V(\Omega)\to C_c^\infty(\partial\Omega)\;,\;\;\;[\theta]\mapsto\langle\left.\theta\right|_{\partial\Omega},\nu_{\partial\Omega}\rangle\tag1$$ is an isomorphism.
> How can we show that?

It's been a while, since I thought about quotient spaces. What would be "canonical" surjection for this quotient space?

Comment: How does the book define $C_c^\infty(\partial\Omega)$?

Comment: @md2perpe I can't find the definition, but since $\partial\Omega$ is a manifold, I guess it's the space of $C^\infty$-differentiable functions $\partial\Omega\to\mathbb R$ with compact support.

Comment: According to the map in (1) $C_c^\infty(\partial\Omega)$ is a vector field on $\partial\Omega$. That's what I find a bit strange.

Comment: @md2perpe Sorry, I've fixed $(1)$. Now it should make sense.

Comment: What do you get with $\Omega$ the unit disk of $\Bbb{R}^2$

Comment: @md2perpe Maybe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3860200/47771) helps to understand my intend and gives context.

Comment: @reuns Well, in the case of a closed unit ball $\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb R^d:\left\|x\right\|\le1\}$ in $\mathbb R^d$, $\nu_{\partial\Omega}(x)=x$ for all $x\in\partial\Omega$.

Comment: So do you see an injection $C_c^\infty(\partial \Omega)\to C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}^d)\to C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}^d ; \Bbb{R}^d)$ ?

Comment: @reuns No, I don't see such an injection. We can clearly extend any $C_c^\infty(\partial\Omega)$ to a function $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ (since $\partial\Omega$ is $\mathbb R^d$-closed in that example), but this extension is clearly not unique.

Comment: Why do you care of unicity ? I'm asking if you can construct an injection whose composition with your map $[\theta]\mapsto\langle\left.\theta\right|_{\partial\Omega},\nu_{\partial\Omega}\rangle$ is the identity (I'm sure you do in case of the disk, the general one is a bit more abstract)

Comment: @reuns Yes, okay. I guess any map $E:C_c^\infty(\partial\Omega)\to C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$ such that $E(f)$ is an extension of $f\in C_c^\infty(\partial\Omega)$ is trivially injective. And, assuming $\Omega$ is a bounded $d$-dimensional properly embedded $C^\infty$-submanifold with boundary, we could take an extension $\overline\nu_{\partial\Omega}\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)$ of $\nu_{\partial\Omega}\in C_c^\infty(\partial\Omega)$. I'm not sure if this is something you've got in mind and I don't know where the special situation of the example kicks in.

Comment: Yes. For the unit ball $f\to f(x/|x|)\phi(|x|-1)\to f(x/|x|)\phi(|x|-1)x$ where $\phi \in C^\infty_c(-1/2,1/2),\phi(0)=1$

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I think the problem is that I don't get the (obvious) point how this is related to showing that $(1)$ is an isomorphism. And what is the purpose of the map you've provided in your last comment? It should be a particular choice for how we can extend a function in $C_c^\infty(\partial\Omega)$ to a function $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$, but I already know that such an extension exist (and I don't see how the particular choice should be of importance, if this is supposed to be your point).

Comment: @reuns Is the existence of a "unitary" extension of $\nu_\partial\Omega$ what you're trying to hint me to? If that's the case, I've already asked for this and received [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3841211/47771). So, I'm aware of that.

Comment: Once the map $[\theta]\mapsto\langle\left.\theta\right|_{\partial\Omega},\nu_{\partial\Omega}\rangle$ is surjective then it is an isomorphism $\mathcal D(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)/\mathcal V(\Omega)\to C_c^\infty(\partial\Omega)$ (quotienting by the kernel..). I'm saying that in the case of the unit ball everything is explicit, and it needs a bit of imagination to see it works the same way for any manifold and $\nu$

Comment: Okay, I think I begin to understand your point. Maybe you're using a different definition of $C_c^\infty(-1/2,1/2)$. Mine is that this would be a space of functions on $(-1/2,1/2)$, but you surely want $\phi$ to be defined on all of $\mathbb R$. So, I guess you mean $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ with $\operatorname{supp}\phi\subseteq(-1/2,1/2)$. But what's the point of considering $(-1/2,1/2)$? Couldn't we take any $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ with $\phi(0)=1$ and $\phi(-1)=0$?

Comment: @reuns Please take note of [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3860842/47771). Do you agree? And please take a look at my follow up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3860200/47771.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question should be reformulated in order to actually make sense:

Therefore, let $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb N\uplus\{\infty\}$ and assume that, more generally, $\Omega$ is a $k$-dimensional embedded $C^\alpha$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary.

We know that

1. if $\partial\Omega$ is $\mathbb R^d$-closed, then every $C^{\alpha-1}$-differentiable map $\partial\Omega\to F$, where $F$ is a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, has an extension to a $C^{\alpha-1}$-differentiable map $\mathbb R^d\to F$;
2. if $\partial\Omega$ is $\mathbb R^d$-compact, such an extension can be chosen to be compactly supported.

So, if I'm not missing anything, we need to assume that $\partial\Omega$ is $\mathbb R^d$-compact. Now let $E$ be an arbitrary map from $C^{\alpha-1}(\partial\Omega)$ to $C_c^{\alpha-1}(\mathbb R^d)$ with $$\left.E(f)\right|_{\partial\Omega}=f\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in C^{\alpha-1}\tag2$$ and $\overline\nu_{\partial\Omega}\in C_c^{\alpha-1}(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)$ be an extension of $\nu_{\partial\Omega}\in C^{\alpha-1}(\partial\Omega,\mathbb R^d)$. Let $$P:C_c^{\alpha-1}(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)\to C_c^{\alpha-1}(\partial\Omega)\;,\;\;\;\theta\mapsto\left\langle\left.\theta\right|_{\partial\Omega},\nu_{\partial\Omega}\right\rangle.$$ Note that $$\left(P\circ E\overline\nu_{\partial\Omega}\right)(f)=f\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in C^{\alpha-1}(\partial\Omega)\tag3$$ and hence $$C^{\alpha-1}(\partial\Omega)\to C_c^{\alpha-1}(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)\;,\;\;\;f\mapsto E(f)\overline\nu_{\partial\Omega}\tag4$$ is a right inverse of $P$; hence $P$ is surjective. Moreover, $P$ is easily seen to be linear (and continuous) and, by definition, $$\ker P=\left\{\theta\in C_c^{\alpha-1}(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d):\left\langle\left.\theta\right|_{\partial\Omega},\nu_{\partial\Omega}\right\rangle=0\right\}.$$ Thus, by the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms, $$\hat P:C_c^{\alpha-1}(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)/\ker P\to\operatorname{im}P=C_c^{\alpha-1}(\partial\Omega)\;,\;\;\;\theta+\ker P\mapsto P(\theta)=\left\langle\left.\theta\right|_{\partial\Omega},\nu_{\partial\Omega}\right\rangle$$ is an isomorphism.